# href whatsapp link to number

Tags: html, whatsapp

I'm having an issue trying to send Whatsapp messagges through browser using this code:

```
<a href="intent://send/+390123456789#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end">click</a>
```

Using this code, Whatsapp opens correctly but the number is not recognized (i'm trying with my number, which is registered in Whatsapp) saying something like "You're trying to reach a non-Whatsapp number. Invite him or send SMS".

My international code (Italy) is +39.
I've tried 003912345, +3912345, 3912345, 12345, but with no success.

Anyone experienced this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: To those who are trying to link to a WhatsApp number: The above example **only** works for Android and limited by the problem @khepti describes. At the moment of writing, it is **not** possible to link to a WhatsApps number cross-platform to an arbitrary number. (but please, prove me wrong)

Answer (score 0):

You get the message"You're trying to reach a non-Whatsapp number. Invite him or send SMS" because the number you want to use for sending the message to must be present into your phone contact list.

Anyway the attached code you use for the link won't work on iOS.

Try to use: href="whatsapp://send/?text=<>" data-action="share/whatsapp/share"   . The link will open WhatsApp but you will have to manually select the consignee of the message from your contact list, otherwise you could use the ABID code to send the message directly to your contact.

Here you'll find more info about this technique: https://www.macstories.net/tutorials/use-whatsapps-url-scheme-with-drafts-launch-center-pro-or-a-bookmarklet/